# Scraping a dynamic website with Python, how to send post request to get placeholder data?

Tags: python, post, web-scraping

I'm trying to get prices for a specific item in different locations across the US. The site has a text box where you can enter a state and it updates the price but the URL remains the same, which I recently found out means it is dynamic. I'm trying to scrape the prices with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/equipment/detail/1255/0350140/7500lb-mini-excavator/').text


soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    # Finding the equipment name and printing it

name_article = soup.find('div', id = 'equipment-catalog-page-container')

    # This pricing is based off of typing "NC" into the search box

equipment_name = name_article.h1.text
print(equipment_name)


for price_article in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'info--price'):
    equipment_price = price_article.text
    print(equipment_price)
```

and the output is:

```
7,500lb Mini Excavator

Online Rate: 

1 Day: {{RateDaily | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}
1 Week: {{RateWeekly | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}
4 Weeks: {{RateMonthly | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}
```

Where the double curly brackets are (and what's inside them) on the developer tools are numbers and currency type, but I'm trying to scrape it so that I can see the actual figures. I believe the URL I'm calling is using placeholders that is updated with Javascript.

Example of what I'm looking to get as output:
    1 Day: $500 USD
    1 Week: $1000 USD
    4 Weeks: $2000 USD

I took a look at the developer tools, and the Network makes 3 separate post requests to these URLs when you enter a location:

https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/ccdata/user/setshoppinglocation/
https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/equipment/getuserequipmentviewdata/

https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/ccdata/rates/getrates

When I load these sites separately, I get sent to an error page (except for the middle one), but in the Developer tools preview, it displays the correct figures so I'm assuming cookies are involved (?). Am I right in needing to send these 3 post requests? How would I send these requests / build it into my code so that it displays the right pricing information? This is my first real python project so I'm not sure if I'm doing this the hard way or if I'm asking the right questions!

Comment: it might be easier to use a headless browser in selenium to get the rendered web contents, then you can use either selenium of bs4 to scrape the data you need

Comment: @TenaciousB I saw selenium popping up a lot when I was doing some google searches. Would this be viable if I'm eventually trying to make a loop so that it searches different locations in the search box?

Comment: I think you can put your own text in the text boxes and even click on things in selenium

Comment: Welp, when I try getting all the html content of that page with selenium i get `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` might be detecting the bot